# How to get reference of component itself and defined variable in Angular 2

Tags: dart, angular

How to get a reference of the component "Cart" itself instead of using querySelector() in class Cart?

Also, I want to know is there anyway to access the variable #i from class Cart?

```
@Component(
    selector: '[cart]',
    templateUrl: 'cart.html')
class Cart  {

    handling(){
         querySelector("div[cart]");
    }
}

<div cart>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#i of items.values">{{i}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do. You can inject ElementRef into your cart constructor `constructor(private _element:ElementRef)` to get the Angular2 element wrapper. nativeElement property has to underlying dom

Comment: Why would you want to access `#i`, it's a value from `items` which is available in `Cart` anyway.

Comment: Hi Chandermani.
Thanks for your helpful hint, it solve my first problem.

Comment: Hi  Günter Zöchbauer. 
Not only #i. In fact, I want to know anyway can access variables defined in a template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Component(
    selector: '[cart]',
    templateUrl: 'cart.html')
class Cart  implements AfterViewInit {
    // as mentioned by @Chandermani
    ElementRef _element;
    Cart(this._element);

    @ViewChildren('myLi') ElementRef myLis;
    // or for a single element or just the first one
    // @ViewChild('myLi') ElementRef myLi;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      // not initialized before `ngAfterViewInit()`
      print(myLis);
    }

    handling(){
         querySelector("div[cart]");
    }
}

<div cart>
   <ul>
      <li #myLi *ngFor="let i of items.values">{{i}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Günter! It is very helpful.

Comment: What exactly does "Cart(this._element);" do here?

Comment: @Cuel it's like `constructor(private _element:ElementRef)` in TS

Comment: Ah. Lots of nifty stuff :)